# Why is my bootloader not loading the second sector to memory?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, bios, floppy

I am trying to write a bootloader to a Virtual Floppy Drive inserted in a VirtualBox VM. Here is the following code that I have:

```
org     0x7c00              ; We are loaded by BIOS at 0x7C00

bits    16                  ; We are still in 16 bit Real Mode

Start: jmp loader
        
loader:

.Reset:
    mov     ah, 0x0                 ; reset floppy disk function
    mov     dl, 0x0                 ; drive 0 is floppy drive
    int     0x13                    ; call BIOS
    jc      .Reset                  ; If Carry Flag (CF) is set, there was an error. Try resetting again

.Load:
 
    mov     ax, 0x07e0              ; we are going to read sector to into address 0x07e0:0
    mov     es, ax
    xor     bx, bx
 
    mov     ah, 0x2             ; read floppy sector function
    mov     al, 0x1                 ; read 1 sector
    mov     ch, 0x1                 ; we are reading the second sector past us, so its still on track 1
    mov     cl, 0x2                 ; sector to read (The second sector)
    mov     dh, 0x0                 ; head number
    mov     dl, 0x0                 ; drive number. Remember Drive 0 is floppy drive.
    int     0x13                    ; call BIOS - Read the sector
    jc      .Load
    
 
    jmp     0x07e0:0x0000               ; jump to execute the sector!
    
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0             ; We have to be 512 bytes. Clear the rest of the bytes with 0

dw 0xAA55                   ; Boot Signiture
```

It is supposed to load a small program into memory that prints the letter 'A' on the screen using a BIOS interrupt. This program is located on the second sector of the floppy disk:

```
org 0x07e0

    xor     bx, bx      
    mov     ah, 0x0e
    mov     al, 'A'
    int     0x10
    cli
    hlt
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not loading? I have tried loading to another address in memory 0x1000, however, this does not work either. Are there certain areas in the virtual memory that are reserved by VirtualBox?

Thanks!!

H

*Edit:

I build my code using nasm for Windows (nasm -f bin -o bootS1.bin bootS1.asm), and then copy and paste the hex from the binary file onto the VFD image using a program called HxD which writes the raw hex data to the disk. The disk is then inserted into the VM and ran to simulate the boot process.

Comment: How do you assemble and run your code?  Please provide the exact comments you type to make the disk image.

Comment: @fuz I've added an edit :)

Comment: There's two files in your project but you only provided the instructions for one of them.

Comment: Note that your boot loader reads from floppy drive 0.  So it'll only work if the code is loaded as that.  Copying it a virtual hard drive won't work.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I do the same process for the second file: nasm -f bin -o bootS2.bin bootS2.asm, and then I copy that hex to the second sector of the floppy using HxD.

Comment: Also note that `org 0x07e0` is incorrect.  The offset at which your payload is loaded is 0 in segment `0x07e0`.  So it should be `org 0x0000` (or just no `org` directive at all).  Given that you do not refer to any addresses in the payload, this does however not cause the problems you observe.

Comment: As for the bootloader reading from floppy drive 0: I'm not using a virtual hard drive, I am using a virtual floppy disk.

Comment: On a side note I suggest you use Bochs for development, it has an internal debugger that comes pretty handy ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 Oh cool thanks, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading from track 1 whereas the payload is on track 0.  Remember: heads and tracks count from 0, sectors from 1.

Note that instead of hard-coding a disk number, you should use the number provided by the BIOS in `dl`.

Also note that `org 0x07e0` is incorrect. The offset at which your payload is loaded is 0 in segment `0x07e0`. So it should be `org 0x0000` (or just no `org` directive at all). Given that you do not refer to any addresses in the payload, this does however not cause the problems you observe.